# Auto Repair Garage Manager

Tags: web-apps, car, repair

I need some help to find a Auto Repair Garage Manager web based solution.
It will be great if possible to be a CMS based (Maybe WordPress, because I'm familiar with it.)
I'm looking for something that will have one time payment, not monthly fee payments.

I'm looking to use it for :

- keep track of past works done on my clients cars and orders from auto parts dealers;
- generate quotes and invoices;
- appointments and scheduling;
- customer and vehicle search by make, model, color, year, etc. but by licence plate as well;
- reporting

I tried my find something using Google, but the results that I got, there were far from I need.

I'm based on Dublin, Ireland and it will fab if I will adapt based on my need, local measurements units, local currency, VAT, etc.

Thank you in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin for WordPress which may help you:

Participants Database

> This plugin offers all the functionality needed to build and maintain
>   a database of people or anything you want. The database is fully
>   configurable, allowing you to define all the fields of information you
>   want to store for each record. The records can be entered individually
>   in the WordPress admin section, imported with a CSV file, or let the
>   individuals themselves create their own record. Display lists of
>   records can be sorted and filtered by any field, and the result
>   exported as a CSV file.

[Participants Database Plugin Page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/participants-database/)

Comment: Hi,

onurcano22, your solution is not "plug and play" but it is interesting. At this moment I'm not very sure if it will work for me or not (having in mind that I need to do bookings, invoices, quotations and all should be visible just for the admin), but I'm more then happy to try your suggested solution. 

It might be very helpful to tell me more about did you come up with this solution and how you will see it working.

I'm still open to any suggestion from you guys.

Thank you onurcano22 for taking time and reply to me and finding a solution for my project!

Comment: I used this plugin for a short period of time. If you know about databases, this seems like it very much. It creates some tables, but no relationship I guess. You could install WordPress and try this in a local server using Wampp, Laragon etc..